# UIPickerView sound

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am looking for the "tick" sound played by UIPickerView as you scroll through elements. Is there a directory in which I can find this file? Or maybe a link to this file?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/scrollerClick.wav`

(or similar, depending on where you installed the developer tools)

Answer (score 2):

With the latest simulators you can find it at the following path:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator**IOS_VERSION**.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/scrollerClick.wav`

Where `**IOS_VERSION**` is e.g. 5.0, 5.1, 6.0

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but while that file exists I can't hear it either using Quick Look or VLC. Any ideas?